# Need help with an online puzzle from m4tr1x.ws

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

I found this online riddle at [m4tr1x.ws](https://m4tr1x.ws/), but now I am stuck. It seems you need to gain deeper and deeper access to this virtual Matrix-style computer system. First you need to create an account via the `register` command. That is easy, after confirming via email you can login to the system.

Afterwards you need to connect to the site via a Tor browser. It turned out the address to connect via Tor is "matrix4ozv2gicar.onion". Connected via Tor you can login again with your user and issue the command `redpill tor`.

Now you gained level 2 of this riddle. Writing just `redpill` now gives you the following:

```
bruteforce SHA224: f6d54a854ca1d0e987b798e1593de79631b8f2329fb84a15725bf9b2
```

And here I am stuck. I have no idea how to decrypt that string. Does one really have to brute-force it? That doesn't feel like the real answer to that problem. I tried several Matrix-related phrases and words, but without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have fed every word in a bunch of electronic wordlists, and in some text I fetched from the web some time ago for a word-analysing project, into Python's `hashlib.sha224` function, with various different capitalizations, and nothing has come back with the hash value given here.

Comment: I suspect that further progress may depend on details within this super-sketchy-sounding game, which I for one am not going to go anywhere near :-). Puzzles here need to be self-contained, and it's beginning to look to me as if this one effectively isn't...

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71985/need-help-with-an-online-puzzle-riddle)

Comment: I would be careful - this could be a hacker way to get to you.

Comment: @Adam Also closed there as off-topic -- which it is; I don't think it's obviously off-topic here, _unless_ there's a real dependence on material not shown here ... which there well might be.

Comment: They say you can use a help command to list all the available commands at https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/comments/3zi36z/m4trix_onion/.

Comment: I can't be the only one not willing to go anywhere near a website ending in .ws... and with a ton o letters replaced with numbers? That is one of the sketchiest sites I have ever seen (I'm not actually going on it, but from the URL.

Comment: In the words of @Bass on [this related post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100932/need-help-with-a-online-puzzle-riddle?noredirect=1&lq=1), "This is not a puzzle, it's a hash cracking challenge."

Answer (score 2):

Well maybe this kind of puzzle (Puzzles must not be from active competitions) belongs to this site, but I guess it is not "that kind" of competitive, so here is the answer:

> wc0sw

One can check it [here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha224.html)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a tool like 'hashcat'. I used it in kali linux.

```
 hashcat -m 1300 -a 3 (hash)
```

I think the hash is auto-generated, as cracking mine gave me:

> kkooc

Entering that gets me to level 3 and after typing redpill it outputs the text: "Under construction".