# Need help with a online puzzle / riddle

Tags: computer-puzzle

I found a puzzle on the deep web (http://matrix4ozv2gicar.onion), and I am stuck on access level 2, I am aware someone else posted the same question on the same part as me about a year ago, except it seems that the website has changed so the answer back then is not useful anymore.
To get to the point where I am you need to register an account using the `register` command, then `login`, and then use the `redpill` command. Now this is where I am stuck, the only thing I have to work with is the redpill command again and when I use it, it says:

```
"bruteforce SHA224: 249dc3df34e1426569c585f582865b58307d76a3a5c167927962f3ea"
```

I have looked around the internet as best as I could to find how to get past this step, but I have found literally no talk apart from that post from one year ago
([Need help with an online puzzle / riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86212/need-help-with-an-online-puzzle-riddle))

Something to note as well is that the post from a year ago is using the clearnet version of this site (https://m4tr1x.ws) while I am using the tor version, which is actually different because the `tor` command only works on the tor browser (with the onion link)

Does anyone know how to get past this section?

Comment: im pretty sure nobody can access the first link... if you aren't on the deep web

Comment: This is not a puzzle, it's a hash cracking challenge.

Answer (score 3):

The puzzle tells you exactly what you have to do, you need to brute force the provided SHA 224 hash to find the password that is encrypted to get the hash. You can either write a program to do so for you, or use an existing password cracking tool to do it. Kali Linux supports SHA 224 cracking, Cain and Abel might, I'm not sure. Depending on the length and complexity of the password it can take minutes to months to crack the hash, I don't think it's really feasible to expect others to spend the time and computing resources for you.

Comment: Kali Linux = Life